# Why does join command in Unix says my files are not sorted?

Tags: sorting, unix, join

I have been trying to use join on two files I have, on a specific column for each file (18th for fileA, 1rst for fileB), and it tells me the files are not sorted. I did use the command sort on those files and cannot understand what is going on.

I tried using the following commands and obtained the same result (which is: "file is not sorted"):

```
join -1 18 -2 1 <(perl -p -e s'/"//'g fileA|sort -k 18) <(sort -k 1 fileB)|less
join -1 18 -2 1 <(perl -p -e s'/"//'g fileA|sort -n -k 18) <(sort -n -k 1 fileB)|less
join -1 18 -2 1 <(perl -p -e s'/"//'g fileA|sort -V -k 18) <(sort -V -k 1 fileB)|less
```

A typical fileA line looks like:

```
chr8    848289  852184  a       0       +       chr8    StringTie       transcript      848290  852184  3895    +       .       gene_id Genome.106729; transcript_id Genome.106729.1; reference_id refGenome_T001.mrna1; ref_gene_id refGenome_T001.path1; ref_gene_name refGenome_T001; cov 342.423218; FPKM 8.291647; TPM 12.997114;       3895
```

A typical fileB line looks like:

```
Genome.106729.1  2078
```

I understood that files had to be sorted by the column used in join, but it does not seem to be working. Can someone please help me?

Best regards

---

I found what was going on. The command was alright, except that I did not have space to create files in my folder, and there was a blank line at the beginning of one of my files. I think the unavailable space made it so that sort could not create anything in memory, which caused the error.

Comment: `perl -p -e s'/"//'g` is better written `tr -d '"'`

Comment: did not knew this command, thanks!

Comment: If your problem is sorting, start by givingn code limited to sorting. Find the smallest code that wrongly extends code that you show works. [mcve]

Comment: thanks for the advice! I understood what was going on in the end but will do that if I have another question.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was going on. The command was alright, except that I did not have space to create files in my folder, and there was a blank line at the beginning of one of my files. I think the unavailable space made it so that sort could not create anything in memory, which caused the error.